# How do I localize a Chrome Extension to a languages that is not available in Web Store?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, internationalization, locale

According [locale table](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n#localeTable) from Web Store are 54 available position. None of them, for example, locales for Kazakhstan or Uzbekistan.

How I can fill `message` for not available locale by `chrome.i18n.getMessage(key, data)` ([docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n))?

If I change an attribute `default_locale` from `en` to `kk` or `uz` raised error about the wrong manifest.

## Update

I try to use `jquery.i18n` ([github](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n)). With localization `html` is okay. But I have problem with inner text from code.

For example, const item with method `getMessage()`. It's run immediately after start extension. At this time, `jquery.i18n` isn't load file with locale text yet. And `getMessage()` return id `noduplicate_title`, no value by id.

How can I load a file with text before to start the extension?

```
const NODUPLICATE_MENU_ITEM = {
    title: getMessage('noduplicate_title')
};

let url = chrome.extension.getURL('localization/languages/en.json');
$.i18n().load({
    en: url,
});

$.i18n({
    locale: 'en',
});

function getMessage(key, data) {
    return $.i18n(key, data);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to use a different JS library for localization, there are many, use search.

Comment: @wOxxOm may you check update post?

Comment: You'll have to assign the value after reading the file.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah, but how?

Comment: I don't know that library, but logically thinking it must have some kind of `load` or `onload` callback. If it doesn't then use a different library.